# Change font color for multiple word documents

Tags: ms-word

I've been tasked with making changes to 2000+ word documents and one of the edits is changing the font color. I know nothing about coding but is there a VBA code or a free software I can use to bulk edit them?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Change the font colour for the entire document or just parts of the doc? Do you want to make similar changes across all 2k docs or different docs need different adjustments?

Comment: I need to change the font colour of the entire document and its the same change to all docs.

Comment: So this can easily be done using VBA. But have you explored anything yet? Simply record a macro by changing colour of one document and then use a loop to implement the same steps for all 2k docs.

Comment: Ok cheers. Will do that.